# copy content of array row by row

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to copy one array("in") content which has 160 elements to another array("temp") which has 16 elements using for loop.In every round in loop one row will be copied from 160 elements array into the new array which has 16 elements 
I use this one but it is not correct.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < ROWSS; i++) 
  {   

    std::array<unsigned char,16> temp = in[i*16];
```

the function :

```
InputDifferences(unsigned char * in, unsigned char * result,unsigned char *  xi)
```

{
    `unsigned char yi[16];
    unsigned char temp[160];
    int index;`

```
/for(int x=0 ; x<ROWS ; x++)
 {
  //unsigned char temp[160] = in[x*16];
 //std::array<unsigned char,160> B = in;
  for ( int i = 0; i < ROWSS; i++) 
  {   


    std::cout << "\nTables:\n";
    for(int a = 1; a < ROUND; a++)
    {   
        std::cout << "\nROUNDS:\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) 
         {
            yi[i*COLS+j] = xi[i*COLS+j] ^ (a);  //x (xor) 1,2,3.. and find input differences
            index = temp[i*COLS+j] ^ temp[yi[i*COLS+j]];    // s(x) (xor) s(y) find output differences
            result[a*16+index]++;   // to find how many appears in each box
         }

    }
    std::cout << "\nTry :" << i; 
    showMatrix2(result); 
  }
```

//}
}

the result will be like this

```
for i =0   temp[16] = in[0..15]
for i = 1  temp[16] = in[16..31]
```

and so on
Could you please help me on this ?

Comment: `temp[16]` is out-of-range, so do not expect it!

Comment: yeah i know, how can it be possible to do this ? Do you know the way without using any other loops ?

Comment: @Sossenbinder I can not use two 2d array because all program works with in[160] and it is a one dimensional unsigned char 
i can not use any other loops as well because this loop has inner loops

Comment: have you tried doing it recursively?

Comment: Nope @Cruiser i don't know how i can do it recursively. Can you provide the code please ?

Comment: No using loop? It may be unrolling the loop like `temp[0] = in[i*16]; temp[1] = in[i*16+1]; ... temp[15] = in[i*16+15];`

Comment: recursively would get you around the no loop restriction, but it's definitely more complicated. i would use another loop first. just a short while loop.

Comment: In your question you say that `in` has 160 elements and `temp` 16, then in your code you declare `temp[160];` and `in` disappear... By the way what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
//declare temp[16] outside for loop
for(int i=0;i<ROWSS;++i){
    int j = 0;
    while(j<16) temp[j] = in[j+i*16];

//the rest of your code
}
```

note that unless you make a new array each time the while loop executes, temp[] will get overwritten with the next 16 numbers.